OpenCV Extract HMDB51 frame but always miss the last frame, and I get the number of frames less than cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT
When I try to extract frames from some videos of the HMDB51 dataset, I find I get fewer frames than expected, the code is
def dump_frames(vid_path):
    # import cv2
    # video = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_path)
    video =
    vid_name = vid_path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
    out_full_path = os.path.join(out_path, vid_name)

    # fcount = int(video.get(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

    fcount = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    print("Total frame count is", fcount)
    try:
        os.mkdir(out_full_path)
    except OSError:
        pass
    file_list = []
    for i in range(fcount):
        ret, frame = video.read()
        # print(i, fcount)
        # assert ret
        cv2.imwrite('{}\\{:06d}.jpg'.format(out_full_path, i), frame)
        access_path = '{}\\{:06d}.jpg'.format(vid_name, i)
        file_list.append(access_path)
    print('{} done'.format(vid_name))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    return file_list
dump_frames("April_09_brush_hair_u_nm_np1_ba_goo_0.avi")

The video can be found here
How can I get the full number of all the frames?

yeah that can happen if the source material is janky. try it with PyAV, or ffmpeg on CLI. -- fundamentally, the data in video files is best addressed by timestamp, not by "frame index". the "frame count" is calculated from duration and assumed frame rate. to know the real number of frames, you'd have to demux the whole thing and read the video bitstream (not necessarily decode it).

a successful [mre] includes the data it requires. you might want to link to an easily accessible source of that dataset, i.e. people can get that one video file.

drive link says "You need access. Request access, or switch to an account with access. Learn more" -- if the file is ~147 kB and looks like the one on this page: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/jesslyn13517053/dataset then just link to it, or the original source of the dataset

ffprobe -show_frames -of json April_09_brush_hair_u_nm_np1_ba_goo_0.avi shows that the PTSes jump ahead a little, i.e. it's not always the same increment. on top of that, it appears to contain (near) duplicate frames
